# Assistance With Setting up Gatsby and WordPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, authentication, gatsby

I have worked on several web dev projects but have never actually built one from the group up (setting up all the backends was already done by the time I arrived).

Am working on building a site and I need some guidance as the process is incredibly confusing to me.

I want to use WordPress as a headless CMS (so that I can still post and manage the site from WP without editing code) and I was looking to use Gatsby.js.

I have a site on WordPress.com (call it: mysite.wordpress.com). I have created my Gatsby site, run it, nice, and installed the `gatsby-source-wordpress` package. Finally, I have my config file as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: { 
    title: `MySite`,
    description: `Testing`,
    author: `Me`
  }, 
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-wordpress",
      options: {
        baseUrl: "mysite.wordpress.com",
        protocol: "http",
        hostingWPCOM: false,
        useACF: true,
        verboseOutput: true,
        auth: {
          htaccess_user: "xxxx@gmail.com", // My actual general WP account email  
          htaccess_pass: "yyyy",           // My actual general WP account pass. I know this is bad practice, I will put this into a dotenv file, I just want to make sure this works 
          htaccess_sendImmediately: false,
        },
      },
    },
  ]
}
```

However, this is not working and I am not sure why. When I run `gatsby develop` I get the following output:

```
 ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-wordpress" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Cannot convert undefined or null to object



  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

  - Function.keys

  - fetch.js:534 getValidRoutes
    [emrose]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/fetch.js:534:26

  - fetch.js:148 fetch
    [emrose]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/fetch.js:148:23

  - task_queues.js:93 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5

  - gatsby-node.js:87 async Object.exports.sourceNodes
    [emrose]/[gatsby-source-wordpress]/gatsby-node.js:87:18

  - api-runner-node.js:235 async runAPI
    [emrose]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:235:20

  - api-runner-node.js:328 async module.exports
    [emrose]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/api-runner-node.js:328:18

  - source-nodes.js:86 async module.exports
    [emrose]/[gatsby]/dist/utils/source-nodes.js:86:3

  - index.js:403 async module.exports
    [emrose]/[gatsby]/dist/bootstrap/index.js:403:3

  - develop.js:419 async module.exports
    [emrose]/[gatsby]/dist/commands/develop.js:419:7


warn The gatsby-source-wordpress plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need it?
```

Despite several hours of googling and youtube'ing, I am not quite clear on how to proceed or if the site I have on my general WP account is even accessible in this format.

I have tried looking for a solution online for quite some time now without success. Keeping in mind that I do intend this site to eventually go live, any guidance on next steps would be awesome (:

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you add more detail regarding what isn’t working?

Comment: Just updated the post @mlunt